# i want to validate text box which should not accept just white space but it should allow white space in between words when entered.in java script

Tags: javascript

```
function nospaces(t) {
   if(t.value.match(/\s/g)) {
     alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to enter any spaces');
     t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `^` and `$` anchors, i.e `!/^\s+$/.test(str)`

Comment: Always helps to provide sample input and expected results as per [mcve]

Comment: You can do this using string functions, something like `!t.value.trim()`, if this expression is `true`, the text box contains only white spaces.

Comment: can someone edit my code and help me with this code please.i am new at this if there is something wrong in the way I asked questions please don't mind.

Comment: Hey, if one of the answers was the correct solution to your problem, could you please select one? If not, you can leave comments to see what additional information users need to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using regex, you could see if the input matches. This function will return `true` if the parameter is empty, or just whitespace. Otherwise, it will return `false`.

```js
function isWhiteSpaceOrEmpty(valueString) {
    return /^\s*$/.test(valueString);
}
```

To explain, lets breakdown the regex used: `/^\s*$/g`

`/` The beginning of the regex

`^` Starts looking at the start of the string

`\s*` Checks to see if there are 0 or more whitespace characters

`$` Checks to see if it is the end of the string

`/` The end of the regex

This means that the only possible strings which could satisfy this, would be ones that are

- empty
- contain only whitespace between the start and end of the string

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex can be
`/^[A-z\d!@#$%^&*()?~]*$/g`
You can add more special character in between the [ ] to accept those special characters...